# regular expression preg_match PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get contents between two curly brackets or **Smarty** tag. I want to get variables with smarty function only, ignoring `if`'s, etc.

Here are the sample string tags:

`{{$variable|lower}}` [should be matched]

`{{$variable|escape:javascript}}` [should be matched]

`{{$variable|str_replace:"search":"replace"}}` [should be matched]

`{{if $test eq "test"}}` [should **NOT** be matched]

`{{section name=foo start=10 loop=20 step=2}}` [should **NOT** be matched]

If I do this

```
preg_match_all('/{{\$?(\w+?[\W\w]*?)}}/',$str,$matches)
```

It gets everything within the brackets.

```
preg_match_all('/{{\$?(\w+?\W*?\w*?)}}/',$str,$matches);
```

This only gets "variable|escape".

Please help with correct regular expression.

Thanks

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? There may be a better way than trying to re-engineer the already badly engineered Smarty.

Comment: @Michael I wish I could +10 that

Comment: @DaveRandom My two biggest programming regrets are built around Smarty.

Comment: :)
I am trying to get the variables from Smarty tags. Actually these variables are stored in database and I am querying database with variables as keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but wouldn't simply:

```
preg_match_all('/\{\{(\$[^|]+)\|[^}]+\}\}/',$str,$matches);
```

do the trick, where `$matches[1]` will hold the variables. If the files contain carriage returns (windows' \r\n), try `'/\{\{(\$[^|]+)\|[^}]+\}\}/s'`, with the `s` modifier

to include matches like: `{{$var}}`

```
//{{$var|foo}} {{$varbar}} bar  as test string
preg_match_all('/\{\{(\$[^|}]+)(\|[^}]+|)\}\}/s',$str,$matches);
//shorter still:
preg_match_all('/\{\{(\$[^|}]+)\|?[^}]*\}\}/s',$str,$matches);
```

returns:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '{{$var|foo}}',
    1 => '{{$varbar}}',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '$var',
    1 => '$varbar',
  ),
  2 => //not in the array when using the second pattern
  array (
    0 => '|foo',
    1 => '',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention but is it possible if it can support only {{$variable}}?

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest me some nice RegEx tutorials?

Comment: Well, I've learned the basics in JS console, using [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) as my main reference. They've got some info on php regex's, too though. I also went through lots of trial and error to get to grips with it all, but [functions online](http://www.functions-online.com), [writecodeonline](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and [codepad](http://codepad.org/) are good sandboxes... basically just keep at it, practice is the best tutor IMHO. just read up on the basics, and practice, I don't think there is a magical tut out there somewhere... sorry

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `\{\{.*?\|.*.+?\}\}`

Comment: Sorry but its matching nothing